# Should a method die if called with a wrong argument?

Tags: perl, methods, error-handling, arguments

Should a method die if called with a wrong argument or continue if possible?

For example:

```
my $n = Something->new( retries => 'hello' );
```

but `retries` would expect an integer.

Comment: bad input = bad output

Comment: If a wrong argument is passed you could throw an exception or return a default value (i.e. 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it depends on the nature of the error. While it isn't the module's decision whether or not any given error is recoverable, it may be best to die anyway and let the calling code use `eval` (or, much better, [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny)) to allow recovery. I mostly copy the built-in functions' behaviour, which die if the *call* is incorrect, but return a failure status if there was an error because of an external problem.

It can be useful to offer default behaviour based on the parameters passed, but never just ignore a parameter if it makes no sense at all. If it's impossible to do anything sensible then rather than dying it should [`Carp`](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp), which reports the error from the context of the calling code.

Answer (score 3):

The method should die as soon as it detects something is wrong. This helps in identifying the problem immediately. If you continue, it will limp along and die somewhere else leaving the program in an inconsistent state which makes it difficult to identify the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

believe it or not, there's a whole philosophical discussion about this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling#Terminate.2Fstop.2Fabort_on_input_problems

I always remember a teacher that always said "what an optimized and wrong program does? lots of wrong answers very fast" :-)

I think errors must interrupt the execution if they are not recoverable. In this case, this is an input data. You can only recover a wrong input data providing a valid default one, which is not fixing the problem, but maskerating it.

So I think it should die.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If a wrong values can be coerced to a valid value, then it might be worth doing so, especially if this helps backwards compatibility. For example, suppose your `Something` class used to be hard-coded to retry either 0 times or 3 times (and thus the `retries` argument was a boolean), but then you rewrote it to accept an integer argument. Then you might want to attempt to continue to accept boolean values...

```
Something->new(retries => "");      # not an integer, but accept as 0
Something->new(retries => undef);   # not an integer, but accept as 0
Something->new(retries => 4);       # an integer, accept as 4
Something->new(retries => "Hello"); # not an integer, accept as 3
Something->new(retries => "World"); # not an integer, accept as 3
Something->new(retries => 1);       # ambiguous!! probably accept as 1
```

If somebody gave you 3.00000105 as an argument, you might just want to round it down to 3. Perhaps they calculated the ideal number of retries based on some complex floating point calculation, and there were rounding errors. You know what they meant.

In other circumstances, it's generally better to die than it is to indicate an error condition via some other mechanism (setting an error flag, returning false, etc).

Answer (score 2):

It depends. It comes down to a situational cost-benefit analysis. To analyze the cost, we need to ask

- How likely is an incorrect value to be passed?
- What are the consequences of an incorrect value being passed?

In the example you gave, an incorrect value have very little consequence, and the user will get a warning. No validation is needed. The best alternative to validation is to create an interface that fails safely, and that's what you have here.

---

The most common consequence to avoiding validation is that warnings and exceptions appear to come from the code that forwent validation code rather than the calling code. So a very important factor for me is:

- How public is this interface?

---

Since there are consequences, you might ask why would one ever avoid validation? There's a very good reason: it requires more code.

- More code to write
- More code to execute (slower).
- More code to maintain.
- More code to debug.
- More chances to make an error.
- More development time needed.

---

If you do decide to add validation, I would have an error result in a warning or an exception, not returning an error.